# How can I initialise a reference member in the default constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Question says it all really.

Would it be better to use const pointer members instead if I were to implement the default constructor?

Comment: use either initializer list or inside the constructor. since this is the default constructor you can initailize inside the constructor. and using reference or const pointer is not much of a difference in default constructor. in parametrized constructor a pointer is better choice..

Comment: If you use a pointer and leave the default constructor you will still have uninitialized member - pointer with undefined value. In both cases you should explicitly initialize the member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the member initialization list:

```
struct foo
{
  const int& ref;
  foo() : ref(some_value()) { }
}
```

Make sure `some_value()` doesn't give you a temporary. It will only have its life extended until the end of the constructor:

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

Comment: Beware: if `some_value` returns a value, you will end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: OK. What I would do would be to call the default constructor of the reference's type. Surely, this would be preferable to using pointer members and initialising to null, right?

Comment: @Frammo A reference needs to refer to some existing object. You can't construct a reference. If you're hoping to have a reference that can sometimes refer to no object, then a reference is not what you want. A pointer is more appropriate for that (or perhaps `boost::optional`).

Comment: @sftrabbit I do want it to refer to an object, but I thought a default constructor is there to construct the object when it's on its own - such as in unit testing. I am a beginner btw so I guess my understanding of the default constructor is a bit out.

Comment: @Frammo The default constructor is there to construct an argument by passing no arguments. That's all a default constructor is - it can take no arguments. If it doesn't make sense to construct an object of your class type without passing anything, then it shouldn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @stfrabbit Ok, thanks for your help. I guess the function you are referring to in the default constructor must be static or global if there are no arguments passed, right?.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends what you want your member to refer to in the default case. A possible solution is to have a default object (possibly some sort of [Null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)):

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : bar_(defaultBar) {}
    Foo(Bar &bar) : bar_(bar) {}

  private:
    Bar &bar_;
    static Bar defaultBar;
};
```

Or, as @sftrabbit shows, you can get a reference to some object from some function.