# Is it bad practice to refer to a dummy object in a mandatory-but-unused default ctor?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

This code works, and I've seen similar code online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094552/6027203), among other places), but it feels bodgy as all get out:

```
struct CategoryData {
private:
    vector<Tag> default_tags() { return vector<Tag>(0); }
public:
    vector<Tag> & tags;
    MiscStuff bundle_of_stuff;
    CategoryData(vector<Tag> & tags, MiscStuff bundle) : tags(tags), bundle_of_stuff(bundle) {} // this ctor is used
    CategoryData() : tags(default_tags()) {} // this ctor is unused, but required
}
```

The default ctor is required, and within each ctor it's required to initialize `tags`. But there's no default `vector<Tag>` for me to reference apart from an empty vector.

I mainly ask because I'm new to C++ and don't have a handle on the intricate differences between reference use and (smart) pointer use. If I find myself with code like this—being forced to use a reference to a dummy object that has no purpose within my program design—should I actually be using a (smart) pointer instead?

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: At least make sure your code is correct before pasting it, what are `related_tags` and `default_related_tags`? I'm guessing `tags` and `default_tags` respectively, but that isn't bad practice, it's just wrong, it won't compile, you can't bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference.

Comment: Why is the default ctor required?

Comment: Sorry all, I'm really sloppy when I try to Minimalize code for SO. Typos fixed.

Comment: @Barry C2512 (i.e. "'CategoryData::CategoryData': no appropriate default constructor available")

Comment: do you really want the reference to the vector of tags to be a reference to a mutable vector? This is an important question because it will influence the correct design decision.

Comment: Why use a reference for the `tags` member if it has to support default construction? (i.e., Why not use a non-owning pointer for the member?)

Comment: This is definitely a X/Y problem. If your use of this class needs a default constructor that makes no sense, then your use is wrong, not the class. Please post that instead.

Comment: @TheMostCuriousThing default constructors aren't required for types in c++ programs. What are you using the type in that requires the type to be default-constructable?

Comment: We're asking because zombie objects (objects that don't satisfy their contract and are in an invalid state) are indeed considered bad practice as you expected. Sorry, I think we all just mentally went *yes* and then went on to try to solve what we saw as the implied additional question, "how can a zombie object state be avoided in this instance?"

Comment: @jaggedSpire Not your fault...I just get easily frustrated at my inability to ask questions effectively. Any any rate...I have enough information in the comments here to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior if you ever operate on `tags` when it was initialized by the default constructor. So your current code is not viable.

I'm going to infer that you intend `tags` to be a shared resource, in which case your best bet is to use a [`shared_ptr<Tag[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which is designed for resource sharing.

Additionally if you're using a `shared_ptr` it's default construction will be a `shared_ptr` with no managed object, so you can just `default` your default constructor:

```
CategoryData() = default;
```